# Expression: vector subscript out of range (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list

I have a problem with my code. While building I am not getting any errors. But while debugging there is an information: "Expression: vector subscript out of range".

I am going to put the whole code (which is about representing the graph using Adjacency List) in here.
I'd be grateful for each answer.
Thanks.

**Graph.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
public:
    /*
    Adds an edge between given vertices. Third argument is a weight of an edge (1 by default).
    If the edge already exists or we try to add a loop, no edge is added.

    Error handling:
    throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
    - we try to create a loop
    - there are no such vertices
    - if the edge already exists
    */
     virtual void addEdge(int u,int v,int weight=1) =0;

     /* 
     Removes an edge between given vertices. 
     If the edge does not exist, nothing is changed.

     Error handling:
     throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
     - an edge does not exist
     - vertices do not exist
     */
     virtual void removeEdge(int, int) =0;

    /*
    Returns:
    1 if given vertices are connected by an egde
    0 if the vertices are not connected

    Error handling:
    throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
    - vertices do not exist
    */
     virtual int areConnected(int,int) =0;

     /*
    Returns:
    the weight of an edge between given vertices.

    Error handling:
    throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
    - an edge does not exist
    - vertices do not exist
    */
     virtual int getWeight(int,int) =0;

     /*
     Prints the representation of a graph.
     */
    virtual void show() =0;   


    /*
    Returns the number of vertices in a graph.
    */
     virtual int getVerticesCount() =0;

     /*
    Returns the number of edges in a graph.
    */
     virtual int getEdgesCount() =0;    

     /*
     Returns:
     degree of the given vertex

     Error handling:
     throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
    - vertex does not exist
     */
    virtual int getDegree(int) =0;  

    /* Return a pointer to the clone of the graph (with the same representation) */
    virtual Graph* clone() =0;

    /* Return a pointer to the empty graph with n vertices and the same representation */
    virtual Graph* empty(int) =0;

};
```

**AdjacencyListGraph.h**

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class AdjacencyListGraph: 
    public Graph
{
public:
     /*
     creates a graph with given number of vertices and no edges
     */
     AdjacencyListGraph(int n=0);
     /*
     creates a copy of a given graph
     */
     AdjacencyListGraph(const AdjacencyListGraph&); 
     ~AdjacencyListGraph();                 

     void show() override;   
     int getVerticesCount() override;           

     void addEdge(int,int,int) override;
     void removeEdge(int, int) override;
     int getEdgesCount() override;  
     int getDegree(int) override;
     int areConnected(int,int) override;        
     int getWeight(int,int) override; 

     Graph* clone() override;
     Graph* empty(int) override;

private:
    /*
        adjacency list
        add whatever is necessary here
    */
    int n;  
    vector<vector<int>> neighbors;
    vector<vector<int>> weights;

};
```

**AdjacencyListGraph.cpp**

```
#include "AdjacencyListGraph.h"

/*
 creates a graph with given number of vertices and no edges
*/
AdjacencyListGraph::AdjacencyListGraph(int n) : neighbors(0), weights(0), n(n){}

/*
 creates a copy of a given graph
*/
AdjacencyListGraph::AdjacencyListGraph(const AdjacencyListGraph& other)
{
    this->n = other.n;
    this->neighbors = other.neighbors;
    this->weights = other.weights;
}

/* destructor */
AdjacencyListGraph::~AdjacencyListGraph()
{
    neighbors.clear();
    weights.clear();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*
 Prints the representation of a graph. Make sure that weight are visible.
 Exemplary representation:

0: 1(2) 4(5)
1: 0(2)
2:
3:
4: 0(5)

 Complexity O(n^2)
*/
void AdjacencyListGraph::show()
{
    int i=0;
    while(i < this->n)
    {
        cout << i << ": ";
        size_t j=0;
        while(j < neighbors[i].size())
        {
            cout << neighbors[i][j] << "(" << weights[i][j] << ") ";
            j++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }
}

/*
Returns the number of vertices in a graph.

Complexity O(1)
*/
int AdjacencyListGraph::getVerticesCount()
{
    return n;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*
    Adds an edge between given vertices. Third argument is a weight of an edge (1 by default).
    If the edge already exists or we try to add a loop, no edge is added.
    Assume that weights are positive integers.

    Error handling:
    throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
    - we try to create a loop
    - there are no such vertices
    - if the edge already exists

    Complexity O(n)
    */
void AdjacencyListGraph::addEdge(int u,int v, int weight)
{
    //throw invalid_argument("this is the way you throw exception with a given message");   
    if(u==v)
        throw invalid_argument("creating a loop is not allowed");

    int a=1;
    for(int g=0; g<n; ++g)
    {
        if(g!=u)
            continue;
        else if(g==u)
        {
            a=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(a==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    int b=1;
    for(int h=0; h<n; ++h)
    {
        if(h!=v)
            continue;
        else if(h==v)
        {
            b=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(b==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    if(weights[u][v]>0)
        throw invalid_argument("the edge already exists");
    else    
    {
        neighbors[u].push_back(v);
        weights[u][v]=weight;
    }   
}

     /* 
     Removes an edge between given vertices. 
     If the edge does not exist, nothing is changed.

     Error handling:
     throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
     - an edge does not exist
     - vertices do not exist

     Complexity O(n)
     */
void AdjacencyListGraph::removeEdge(int u, int v)
{
    if(weights[u][v]==0)
        throw invalid_argument("the edge does not exist");

    int a=1;
    for(int g=0; g<n; ++g)
    {
        if(g!=u)
            continue;
        else if(g==u)
        {
            a=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(a==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    int b=1;
    for(int h=0; h<n; ++h)
    {
        if(h!=v)
            continue;
        else if(h==v)
        {
            b=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(b==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    for(int j=0; j<n; ++j)
    {
        if(j==u)
        {
            for(size_t i=0; i<neighbors[j].size(); ++i)
            {
                if(neighbors[j][i]==v)
                {
                    weights[u][v] = 0;
                    cout << "the edge is removed";
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
    Returns the number of edges in a graph.

    Complexity O(n^2)
*/
int AdjacencyListGraph::getEdgesCount()
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for(size_t j=0; j<neighbors[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            if(weights[i][j]>0)
                count++;
            else
                continue;
        }
    return count/2;
}

     /*
     Returns:
     degree of the given vertex

     Error handling:
     throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
    - vertex does not exist

    Complexity O(n)
     */
int AdjacencyListGraph::getDegree(int v)
{
    int b=1;
    for(int h=0; h<n; ++h)
    {
        if(h!=v)
            continue;
        else if(h==v)
        {
            b=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(b==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    int degree=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        if(i==v)
        {
            for(size_t j=0; j<neighbors[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                    if(weights[i][j]>0)
                        degree++;
            }
            return degree;
        }
    }
}

    /*
    Returns:
    1 if given vertices are connected by an egde
    0 if the vertices are not connected

    Error handling:
    throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
    - vertices do not exist

    Complexity O(n)
    */
int AdjacencyListGraph::areConnected(int v,int w)
{
    int a=1;
    for(int h=0; h<n; ++h)
    {
        if(h!=v)
            continue;
        else if(h==v)
        {
            a=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(a==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    int b=1;
    for(int h=0; h<n; ++h)
    {
        if(h!=w)
            continue;
        else if(h==w)
        {
            b=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(b==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    for(int j=0; j<n; ++j)
    {
        if(j==v)
        {
            for(size_t i=0; i<neighbors[j].size(); ++i)
            {
                if(neighbors[j][i]==w)
                    if(weights[v][w]>0)
                        return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

     /*
    Returns:
    the weight of an edge between given vertices.

    Error handling:
    throw std::invalid_argument with appropriate message if:
    - an edge does not exist
    - vertices do not exist

    Complexity O(n)
    */
int AdjacencyListGraph::getWeight(int u, int v)
{
    int a=1;
    for(int g=0; g<n; ++g)
    {
        if(g!=u)
            continue;
        else if(g==u)
        {
            a=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(a==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    int b=1;
    for(int h=0; h<n; ++h)
    {
        if(h!=v)
            continue;
        else if(h==v)
        {
            b=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(b==1)
        throw invalid_argument("the vertex does not exist");

    if(weights[u][v]==0)
        throw invalid_argument("the edge does not exist");

    int weight=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        if(i==u)
        {
            for(size_t j=0; j<neighbors[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                    if(neighbors[i][j]==v)
                    {
                        weight=weights[i][j];
                        return weight;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

Graph* AdjacencyListGraph::clone()
{
    Graph *c = new AdjacencyListGraph(*this);
    return c;
}

Graph* AdjacencyListGraph::empty(int n=0)
{
    Graph *c = new AdjacencyListGraph(n);
    return c;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "AdjacencyListGraph.h"

void main()
{
    Graph &g = AdjacencyListGraph(4);
    try
    {
        cout << "add loop (0,0): ";
        g.addEdge(0,0);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }


    try
    {
        cout << "add edge with non-existing end (0,7): ";
        g.addEdge(0,7);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }

    g.show();

    cout << "add edge (0,1,3)"<<endl;
    g.addEdge(0,1,3);

    cout << "add edge (0,2)"<<endl;;
    g.addEdge(0,2);

    cout << "get weight (0,1): " << g.getWeight(0,1) <<" should be 3"  << endl;
    cout << "get weight (0,2): " << g.getWeight(0,2) <<" should be 1"  << endl;

    Graph* g1 = g.clone();
    g1->show();
    try
    {
        cout << "add loop (1,1): ";
        g1->addEdge(1,1);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout << "add edge (1,2)"<<endl;
    g.addEdge(1,2);
    cout << "add edge (2,3)"<<endl;
    g.addEdge(2,3);
    try
    {
        cout << "add duplicate edge (2,3,7): ";
        g.addEdge(2,3);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }
    cout << "get weight (2,3): " << g.getWeight(2,3) << " should be 1"  <<endl;
    g.show();
    cout<<endl;
    g1->show();

    cout << "remove edge (1,2)"<<endl;
    g.removeEdge(1,2);

    try
    {
        cout << "remove non-existing edge (1,2): ";
        g.removeEdge(1,2);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }
    try
    {
        cout << "remove edge with non-existing end (1,7): ";
        g.removeEdge(1,7);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }


    cout << "check edge (0,1): " << g.areConnected(0,1) <<" should be 1"     << endl;
    cout << "check edge (0,3): " << g.areConnected(0,3) <<" should be 0"     << endl;

    try
    {
        cout << "check edge with wrong end (0,7): "<< g.areConnected(0,7);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }
    try
    {
        cout << "check edge with wrong end (-1,7): "<< g.areConnected(0,7);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }


    cout << "vertices: " << g.getVerticesCount() <<" should be 4" << endl;
    cout << "edges: " << g.getEdgesCount() <<" should be 3" << endl;

    cout << "deg(0): " << g.getDegree(0) <<" should be 2" << endl;

    try
    {
        cout << "check degree of non-existing vertex deg(7): " << g.getDegree(7);
        cout<<" - should throw invalid_argument exception"<<endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<" - OK"<<endl;
    }   

    delete g1;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Is that message all the information you get? There's no line number? No file name? No function name? Nothing else? And it's not an exception being thrown, it's just that message somewhere? Where and how do you get that message? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line to see when and where the message appears? Tried to print out all indexes and array/vector sizes for all array/vector access?

Comment: It is in the separate window, and it starts with "Debug Assertion Failed".

Also I found that the mistake is in the AdjacencyListGrapg.cpp file in the function "void AdjacencyListGraph::show()", 
namely I cannot use "neighbors[i].size()". 
Please help me out with replacing this with something that will work similarly.

Comment: I'd suggest debugging and checking what the variable n contains when the program reaches that line. Btw n is a terrible name for a member variable.

Comment: I already checked it, variable n = 4, as it should be, because it is said in main.cpp file.

I was also using iterators or functions front() and back() from std::vector. But nothing worked.

Comment: You basically gave us a whole lot of code and asked us to debug it for you so -1 for that. Having said that, I don't see where you are initializing neighbors so that may be your problem.  Now go debug your code on your own.

Comment: I asked for finding the error which I couldn't find (but finally I managed to find it). So if you don't have any good answer, please don't add any comment which is of no help for me. Thanks.